General Process / Tricks for Finding Extreme points?
This is somewhat of an open ended question, but a few of my textbooks highlight the importance of the Krein-Milman theorem for locally convex TVS's.  However in every example, they seem to pull out seemingly random (and clever) tricks in order to find the extreme points of sets. In many cases, they provide zero explanation.
Here are some examples my textbook mentions, but doesn't explain any of the tricks they use to find these.  Let $B$ be the closed unit ball throughout.

For $p \in (1,\infty)$ and $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space, we have $\text{Ext}(B) = \partial B$.

For $p=1$ and $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $\text{Ext}(B) = \{\alpha \chi_{E} \: | \: \text{$E$ is an atom of $\mu$ and $|\alpha| = \mu(E)^{-1}$}\}.$

For $p=\infty$ and $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space, $\text{Ext}(B) = $

For $X$ compact Hausdorff, $\text{Ext}(B) = \{f \in C(X) \: | \: f(X) \subset \mathbb{T}\}$ in $C(X)$.

For $X$ completely regular, $\text{Ext}(B) = \{f \in C(X) \: | \: f(X) \subset \mathbb{T}\}$ in $C_b(X)$.

For $\mathfrak{H}$ an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, $\text{Ext}(B) = \{T \in \mathcal{B}(\mathfrak{H}) \: | \: \text{$T$ is an isometry or a co-isometry}\}$.


I usually get stuck immediately on these problems spinning my wheels messing with endless amount of annoying inequalities / equations. Take 1. for instance. Let $f \in \partial B$ and assume for contradiction $f$ isn't extreme, then there exists $\lambda \in (0,1)$ and $g \neq h \in B$ such that $$f = \lambda g + (1-\lambda)h.$$  Then: $$1 = \lVert \lambda g + (1-\lambda) h\rVert_p \leq \lambda \lVert g \rVert_p + (1-\lambda) \lVert h \rVert_p \leq 1$$ so that $1 = \lambda \lVert g \rVert_p + (1-\lambda) \lVert h \rVert_p$, but since $1$ is an extreme point of the ball in $\mathbb{C}$ we conclude that $\lVert g \rVert_p = \lVert h \rVert_p$ and hence $1 = \lVert g \rVert_p = \lVert h \rVert_p$ so that $g,h \in \partial B$.  Now $L^q(\mu)^{*} \cong L^p(\mu)$ so there exists $\varphi_g,\varphi_h \in L^q(\mu)^{*}$ such that $\lVert \varphi_g \rVert = \lVert \varphi_h \rVert = 1$ and: $$\varphi_g(\xi) = \int_{X} g(x)\xi(x) \: d\mu(x), \: \: \varphi_h(\xi) = \int_{X} h(x)\xi(x) \: d\mu(x) \: \: \forall \xi \in L^q(\mu).$$  But then for $\xi \in L^q(\mu)$: $$\varphi_f(\xi) = \int_{X} f(x)\xi(x) \: d\mu(x) = \lambda \int_{X} g(x)\xi(x) \: d\mu(x)+ (1-\lambda) \int_{X} h(x)\xi(x) \: d\mu(x)$$ implying $\varphi_f = \lambda \varphi_{g} + (1-\lambda) \varphi_h$.  Now, I can continue to mess with the linear functionals, but I'm pretty much out of ideas..
So given these examples, what are some good tips and tricks to keep in mind?

Generally speaking, spaces that are like $L^p$ spaces with $1 < p < \infty$ behave sort of like Euclidean spaces with their usual norms, so the extreme points are just boundary points. (Formally, these are known as strictly convex spaces: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strictly_convex_space) Spaces that are like $L^1$ have their extreme points corresponding to atoms. And spaces that are like $L^\infty$ have their extreme points things that are “similar to isometries”. (Essentially, functions with range in the unit circle, or isometries and co-isometries in case of $B(H)$.)

$C(X)$ and $B(H)$ are “$L^\infty$-like”, so they all fall under that case. There are various noncommutative versions of $L^p$ spaces, like spaces of Schatten class operators. Those behave like the usual $L^p$ spaces. (Atoms should be reinterpreted as minimal projections in the noncommutative case.)

The same applies to Sobolev spaces, with each corresponding to $L^p$ spaces for some $p$. (There are no atoms in that case.) Also, $C^\ast$-algebras behave like $L^\infty$. The dual space of a space behaving like $L^p$ should behave like $L^q$ (including the $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ cases), and so on.

(A small correction: in case of Schatten class operators, for $L^1$, the atoms should be reinterpreted as all rank-one operators, not just minimal projections.)
